# Hide non-existing image from page using echo function

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following line:

```
<td><img src="Photos/<? echo $rows['photo1']; ?>" height="200" /></td>
```

I don't always have a photo. I would like to hide the image space. It looks like it is broken or if the url is wrong.

Comment: Can't you do `if ($rows['photo1'] != '') ... echo $rows['photo1']` in your template?

Comment: try `onerror="this.style.display='none'` inside the img tag. I have given an example in my answer.

Comment: If you're using a local image, you may check for file existance using `if(file_exists('path/to/image' . $rows['photo1']`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td><?php echo (!empty($rows['photo1']) ? '<img src="Photos/' . $rows['photo1'] . '" height="200" />' : '') ?></td>
```

Comment: My own personal preference, ternaries should be used sparingly, and should NOT be interpolated with template code. WAY too easy to get it wrong. Just my opinion (no downvote).

Comment: I do not think @drftorres separates HTML from PHP. Motto here: "If it looks stupid and it works, its not stupid." :)

Comment: If it looks stupid, and is stupid, it is stupid. If it works, hot damn! (But still...)

Comment: I got your point. I just...while it solves question...why not. Thats all. Everything else is matter of tastes.

Comment: Very true (hence, no downvote). Ternaries are tricky beasts, in that they're complicated in practice to self-document. My preference is a clearly expressive syntax (using `if`s). It's not wrong, but it's oh so not "right". `;)`

Answer (score 1):

**To have no `<img>` tag appear for blank values, I'd use something like this:**

```
<?php if (($rows['photo1'] !== "") || ($row['photo1'])) 
      {
       echo "<td><img src='Photos/" . $rows['photo1'] . "' height='200' /></td>";
      }
?>
```

*if (image is not blank, and it exists) {
then, echo the img tag and the variables
}*

---

**Alternatively, If you want to display a different image for blank values:**

```
<td>
     <img src="Photos/<?php if ($rows['photo1'] !== ""){echo $rows['photo1'];}
                     else {echo "defaultimg.jpg";}?>" height="200" />
</td>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Also, please see @Krynble 's comment above.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this is more to your liking:

```
 <img src="Photos/<? echo $rows['photo1']; ?>" height="200" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
```

It sets the image to not show when there is a problem (such as a broken URL).

This has the advantage of avoiding ternaries, separates PHP from HTML, and keeps things clear without excessive documentation. Hope it helps.